# Pointer initialization concept in C

Tags: c, pointers, initializing

Why is this erroneous?

```
char *p;   
*p='a';
```

The book only says -use of uninitialized pointer. 
Please can any one explain how that is?

Comment: If you declare a pointer it has to point some memory location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char *c; //a pointer variable is being declared 
*c='a';
```

you used the dereferencing operator to access the value of the variable to which c points to but your pointer variable c is not pointing to any variable thats why you are having runtime issues.

```
char *c; //declaration of the pointer variable
char var; 
c=&var; //now the pointer variable c points to variable var.
*c='a'; //value of var is set to 'a' using pointer 
printf("%c",var); //will print 'a' to the console
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: That is really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it may cause a run-time error since it is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The pointer variable is defined (but not properly initialized to a valid memory location), but it needs memory allocation to set value.

```
char *p;
p = malloc(sizeof(char));
*p = 'a';
```

It will work when  `malloc` succeeds. Please try it.

Comment: Ok , do you mean we need to make the pointer to  point some location forcefully. And then only it can be used.. I m trying to get an intiution.

Comment: @RavirajGardi: Yes: if the pointer is not yet pointing to a known location, it cannot be used safely — it can only be assigned to in order to make it point to a defined location or to make it into a null pointer.

Comment: The pointer can be initialized either by malloc() o by taking the address of other char/char-array, wich already own storage, with & operator (address-of).  p=&mycharvar;

Comment: It’s not always useful (let alone necessary) to allocate heap memory. A pointer can just as easily point to a variable on the stack. We don’t know how the OP wants to use the variable, but stack might be the better option - with less risk of forgetting to free up the memory. See P__J__’s answer for both options.

Answer (score 2):

The pointer is not initialized ie it does not point to object allocated by you.

```
char c;
char *p = &c;
*p = 'c';
```

Or

```
char *p = malloc(1);
*p = 'c';
```

Comment: code in 1st line should be `char c;` :-) you could also explain the difference between the both initializations.

Comment: @TomKuschel books are for explaining it. Not the QA portals

Comment: @P__J__: Stack Overflow is for explaining.