# Intializing a pointer from a class, from a different class type, C++

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

I am doing an assignment for my OOP C++ class. I am currently struggling with initializing a pointer. The directions for my assignment from this part state:

> Define a class called FracList with private members fracPtr, a Fraction pointer and size to hold the size of the array of Fraction objects.

My current code, which brings errors, goes like this. Note `Fraction` is another class.

in FracList.h

```
private:
    Fraction *fracPtr;
    int size;
```

in FracList.cpp

```
void FracList::set_ptr(int* p)
{
    fracPtr = p;
}

Fraction *FracList::get_ptr()
{
    return fracPtr;
}

// Default Constructor

FracList::FracList(int s) : size(s)
{
    if (size > 0)
        fracPtr = new Fraction[size];
    else
        fracPtr = NULL;
}
```

How do I properly initialize the `Fraction* fracPtr` pointer variable?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and the error messages from the compiler.

Comment: You should probably be using `std::vector`

Comment: Cheers R Sahu, I will take a look at that link later and edit or repost after reading it. This is my first time posting on this site.
eerorika, we are not using <vector> in this program.

Comment: What is meant by the size variable? Number of elements or size in memory bytes?

Comment: A shot in the dark because if it isn't a problem now, it will be some time soon: [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: Side note: `FracList::set_ptr` needs a lot more smarts. For example, what happens to the storage at which `fracPtr` could already be pointing? If you are not required to write setters and getters for this class, I would not. They will break encapsulation unless you write them very carefully. For example, consider this bit of idiot code: `delete[] myFracList.get_ptr();` `myFracList` has no idea that someone else just destroyed its data. Only badness can result.

Comment: Your `set_ptr()` needs to take a `Fraction*` as input, not an `int*`. It is also leaking memory by not freeing the `Fraction[]` array that `fracPtr` is currently pointing at, before then taking ownership of the caller's pointer (which, in of itself, is bad design). A safer design would be to have a setter that takes a new `size` value instead, and then resize the internal `Fraction[]` array as needed.  Don't let the caller provide a new `Fraction*` pointer at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you probably meant is this:

```
class Fraction{
public:
     Fraction(){}
};

class FracList{
private:
    Fraction *fracPtr;
    int size;
 public:
     Fraction* get_ptr();
    FracList(int s);
    void set_ptr(Fraction* p);
};



void FracList::set_ptr(Fraction* p)
{
    fracPtr = p;
    cout<<"The address of p is:"<< p <<endl;
}

Fraction *FracList::get_ptr()
{
    return fracPtr;
}
int main ()
{
    FracList f1(3);
    Fraction* p=new Fraction;
    f1.set_ptr(p);
    cout<<"the address of p is still:" << p << endl;
}
```

All that you have to do is to understand how to initialize a pointer. `Fraction *fracPtr = p;` This is the right way to do it and the parameter that you have to pass at this function is not an int, it should be a pointer to Fraction because you want to give to your data member an address that it will point to. The concept is similar to pointers in c :[Pointer initialization concept in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53800196/pointer-initialization-concept-in-c)

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. I thank you VERY much Valeri for showing me how to initialize a pointer, along with all of the other comments/links everyone else posted. Much appreciated <3

Comment: You are right I corrected it now to pointer points to the same address